# Don`t send email to customer after woocomerce order status changing

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Please, help to solve the problem. I want to make WooComerce send email only once, about new order - both admin and customer. If I will change order status - NO email will be send.

I've tried to disable notifications at `woocomerce-settings-emails` and disable all notifications for clients, but in this case, clients don`t receive any email even for the first time.

Comment: Please provide a code example to give your question more context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in funtion.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );

function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {

    /**
     * Hooks for sending emails during store events
     **/
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_low_stock_notification', array( $email_class, 'low_stock' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock_notification', array( $email_class, 'no_stock' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_on_backorder_notification', array( $email_class, 'backorder' ) );

    // New order emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

    // Processing order emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

    // Completed order emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

    // Note emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_new_customer_note_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Note'], 'trigger' ) );
}
```